# How to make executable program in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

How to make executable program in java?

Comment: You mean how to make a literal `.exe` binary from a class file or jar package?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to, there are a number of other options available:

- As Philip suggested you can use an executable jar file. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jar/index.html
- You can build on top of a framework that already has its own launcher such as Eclipse. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform
- You can use a technology such as Java web start to launch your app from a browser. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start (or just package your app as an applet)

Comment: I particularly like the 3rd suggestion, which will work on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

probably this may help you 
http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0042.html

there he talks about nice tool called Java2Exe which serves your purpose

Answer (score 1):

The common way is the following:

1. compile your class files: javac *.class
2. create a jar file (it's basically a .zip-file):

   - echo Main-Class: MyMainClassName > manifest.txt
   - jar cvfm MyOwnJarfile.jar manifest.txt *.class
3. create a .bat-script (or sh script if your are on unix):

   - echo java -jar MyOwnJarfile.jar > start.bat
4. Double-Click on start.bat ;-)